# Maximum number of usb devices

Tags: mount

I have two internal harddisks. Ubuntu is installed on the primary one. I found that the other is auto-mounted to `/media`. I then tried to connect two more usb sticks with no problem, they are auto-mounted as well. But when I tried to connect another one, it always fails. It looks like the maximum number of usb devices I can mount is three. Is there a maximum number of usb devices one can mount in Ubuntu?

`lsusb` shows the following:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0616 Genesys Logic, Inc. hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 026: ID 0bc2:5031 Seagate RSS LLC FreeAgent GoFlex USB 3.0
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0781:5581 SanDisk Corp. Ultra
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: The maximum number of USB devices Ubuntu can handle is far greater than the number that you feasibly hold in a backpack. It's more likely a limitation on the USB device itself (is it working properly?) or a limitation on hardware or software support for that device or data on it.

Comment: First, try `lsusb` without the device plugged in, plug it in, then run `lsusb` again, is it recognized?

Comment: Yes, but it's way beyond three, or even four. In a terminal window, type `journalctl --follow`, then connect the USB stick. The log messages will help you understand.

Comment: @robobenklein It is not recognized when I lsusb.

Comment: @waltinator No response when I insert a usb memory stick.

Comment: Is it just that particular stick or is it any USB drive?

Comment: @robobenklein I tried several sticks, all not recognized.

Comment: Is a single USB stick plugged directly into the computer (ie not through a hub) recognized at all? Also, what USB revision are these devices? 3.1/3.0/2.0/1.1?

Comment: If there's a maximum in the software, it's certainly more than 4 (since I have 5 ports and all work at the same time for me). What's probably happening is that your system is not able to provide enough power for more than two devices. Do you have another OS to test?

Comment: @robobenklein If I plug the USB stick directly into the computer not through a hub, it can be recognized. It's USB3.0

Comment: @muru Sorry, I don't have another OS to test.

Comment: If a hub's involved, power is the likely problem. You should try with a USB hub that supports external power.

Comment: This^^^ but I must add that even with a powered hub problems can still occur because some devices do not work well in daisy-chained hubs.